# constantly writing files on SSD Win8 - RAMDISK versus disk cache?

Tags: windows, ramdisk, hard-drive-cache

I have an application that is constantly writing up to 8 x 15Mb files to disk (capturing video streams) with a new file being created each minute (and the oldest file deleted). The computer has a SSD and the application will be running 24x7. I consider this will put a lot of wear on the SSD so was thinking about setting up a RAMDISK. However Win8 has a pretty smart file cache, so I was wondering if it is smart enough to leave these files in cache and not touch the SSD?

The machine has ample RAM free (about 2GB) and it does not matter if the files are lost due to sudden power outage. I'd prefer not to use a RAMDISK due to the extra setup complexity but if its the best option to save SSD wear I will.

If RAMDISK is the best option, any recommendations for freeware RAMDISKs that can dynamically allocate RAM based on need, for both Windows & Linux?

Thanks
Dean

Comment: Why not simply install a small traditional mechanical hdd instead?  I don't consider 2GB of free memory enough to create a RAMDisk

Comment: I could but I want to keep the configuration simple, it's for an embedded system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15MB/minute would reach the rated endurance of a typical SSD in 65 years. And SSDs usually go way past their rated write endurance (unless, of course, they fail for some other reason). So I wouldn't worry about it.

Modern SSDs are easily capable of 150MB/second, which is 600 times more writing than that. So it's definitely possible for write endurance to be an issue. But not at a write rate that low.

Comment: Thanks, I should have been clearer - it is writing up to 8 x 15MB files per minute for 24x7. So that makes it about 8 years which is still pretty good.

Comment: For this scenario, would the Win8 disk cache be writing the updates to the SDD (write-through) or would they be cached (deferred-write)?

Comment: They would be cached, but still likely every byte will hit the disk.

Answer (score 0):

The Tech Report have a long running [SSD endurance test](http://techreport.com/review/25889/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-500tb-update), designed to answer the question of whether SSD wear is a problem.

They saw the the first signs of deterioration at 100TB. You're writing ~170GB/day (15mb * 8 files/min * 60 mins * 24 hrs). So based on that, if you believe the internet, you may want to budget for replacing the disk after, say 2 years. Possibly.

You may want to give a mechanical HDD a go. Various manufacturers have models designed to handle multiple video streams - Seagate even have a version specifically for [video surveillance applications](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/internal-hard-drives/consumer-electronics/sv35/).

Personally I wouldn't bother with the ramdisk approach, I think the memory is better given to the OS to use as it sees fit.

Comment: Thanks, a year isn't a great option. RAMDISK RAM usage wouldn't be a problem as there will be a maximum of 16 x 15MB files at any one time which is only 240MB. I'll only be writing back to persistent storage a couple of these 15MB files per hour so won't need a special disk for multiple video streams.

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting lost in decimal places. It might be more like 10 years. Ach, need to go and scribble out some commas!

Comment: 63TB/year. So 1.5-2 years to a pessimistic first sign of decay based on the internet, although they do say in that article that even allowing for that all the drives are still going after 500TB.